# What is the difference between a simple "fraction" and a "common fraction"?

Tags: fractions, ratio

I have read about a **common fraction** in this statement (written in a text book):

> Ratio is the simplest form of a common fraction, in which the
>   numerator denotes the antecedent and the denominator denotes the
>   consequent.

The Wordweb dictionary defines a common fraction as

> The quotient (*defined as "The ratio of two quantities to be
>   divided" / "The number obtained by division"*) of two integers.

From this definition, a common fraction pretty much seems to be just the same as a *fraction*. **So what is the difference?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I doubt there is any authoritative definition, I've always taken *common fraction* to mean a ratio of two integers, whereas a *fraction* is a ratio of any two things. For example
$$\frac{1}{2},\qquad\frac{17}{2^4},\qquad\frac{12}{24},$$
are common fractions, whereas
$$\frac{\pi^2}{6},\qquad\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\qquad\frac{x^2+3}{x^3-1},$$
are fractions, but not common fractions.

Comment: Hey thank you so very much for answering. But just to be sure, I need to ask that is what you said based on something, or is it just an assumption?

Comment: This is based purely on my personal experience, not on any (other) authoritative source.